# PHP Remove duplicates string on same line of file for all lines?

Tags: php

I apologize for a confusing title. Basically, i'm facing a problem with my website which ends up bugging it completely. I need to basically remove all duplicate entries on the same line, on all lines in my text file list. I.e.

```
123123
123
123
```

Sometimes i get entries like 123123 on the same line when it should just be 123, on each line. This is just an example of course, it's hard for me to explain. I apologize again. I hope this was enough for you to gasp what i mean.

To sum it up, i'm need to remove the duplicate part of the string 123123, so it's just 123, for all of the lines in my text file.

Help appreciated.

A live example for this:

```
2017-06-21:127.0.0.12017-06-21:127.0.0.1
2017-06-21:127.0.0.12017-06-21:127.0.0.1
2017-06-21:127.0.0.12017-06-21:127.0.0.1
2017-06-21:127.0.0.1
```

Comment: It is always the whole line that gets duplicated, or could it also be some smaller part of it?

Comment: this would probably make more sense with real data. and better to fix how the the data is added, than after it has been

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: What will you do if the line was really intended to read 123123?

Comment: It sounds like you don't really know yourself what you need/have/want to do. Make sure you know that.

Comment: @trincot It won't be, it's just an example. My script is an IP & user agent logging script, that removes duplicate lines, but for some reason when the script is removing duplicates, and another user accesses the page to be added to the log it actually makes a same line duplicate.

Comment: @Xatenev Hope that is more clear.

Comment: So shouldn't you fix your original problem that it makes duplicates instead of adding another script?

Comment: @Xatenev Well, because my script is just a search string script, that counts lines of the query. I was just going to add additional code to fix this. The error would be here: https://pastebin.com/SjrcCCRC If anything (the part where i make sure all entries are unique). This issue also occurs when users load the page at the same time.

Comment: stop using flat files by the sounds of it would be a good start.

Comment: @rtfm Don't be apart of the problem, be apart of the solution.

Comment: lol the problem is using the wrong tools in the first place. some times starting again is the RIGHT answer

Comment: you need to provide live examples. not only one. few cases if you want help

Comment: @RobinVanPersi Does that help? That's the string format.

Comment: or just install google analytics and be done with it. if your just counting hits, you can just scrape the access log or there are a dozen tools that do that too.

Comment: @rtfm  It's a unique traffic counter, GA doesn't offer this.

Comment: unique hits? sure does, and it knows a a lot more about 'unique' than just IP (which is basically meaningless (IP !=user))\

Comment: @rtfm It doesn't mate. Plus it counts bots & crawlers as 'users' which falsifies stats completely.

Comment: @rtfm Besides, in GA terms. Users actually = session within past 15 minutes. So it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: no and no but i see you dont care.

Answer (score 0):

A basic algorithm to deduplicate a string:

1. Split it in half.
2. If the both halves are the same, replace the whole string with either half.

Caveat: this doesn't care whether or not the string was *intended* to be a duplicate or not, and consequently may remove some things you don't want it to.

```
function deduplicate($str) {
    $str = trim($str);
    list($beginning, $end) = str_split($str, strlen($str) / 2);
    return ($beginning == $end) ? $end : $str;
}
```

Assuming you have an array of lines from your file you can apply it with `array_map`.

```
$lines = array_map('deduplicate', $lines);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, i added string format to OP, if that helps. Sorry for being such a newb.

Comment: It should still work with that format. It works in my tests using that data, anyway. Maybe there are extra spaces? Try trimming the line before splitting it. I updated the answer.

Comment: btw: I think this process is called "deduplication" no "unduplication"

Comment: @don't-panic It works now, nice! Although I've ran into another problem. It was obvious this was going to happen, I'm an idiot for not thinking of this. Now it happens with IP's that aren't the same. https://i.gyazo.com/466d00a8b8430db3facf9773cdf32193.png (I blured out some my user's IP's for security)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I think you're probably right, but I like making up words. How about "disduplification"?

Comment: @blagol12 well, those aren't duplicates, so yeah, this is fairly useless for them. If all of your lines are supposed to be a date+IP, there's probably a better regex-based solution. But that's kind of a different question from "how to remove duplicates".

Answer (score 0):

```
$linesStr = '2017-06-21:127.0.0.12017-06-21:127.0.0.1
2017-06-21:127.0.0.12017-06-21:127.0.0.1
2017-06-21:127.0.0.12017-06-21:127.0.0.1
2017-06-21:127.0.0.1';

//can be \n only
$lines = explode("\r\n", $linesStr);

//loop through all lines
foreach($lines as $i => $line)
{
  $lineLen = ceil(strlen($line) / 2);
  $first = substr($line, 0, $lineLen);
  $second = substr($line, $lineLen);
  if($first == $second)
  {
      $lines[$i] = $first;
  }  
}

$lines = implode("\r\n", $lines);
```

This should do it...